# How to set up Keycloak 23 with NGINX in Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, containers, keycloak

I have been having trouble setting up communication between my NGINX reverse proxy and my instance of Keycloak running in Azure Container Apps. I am exposing port 443 on the nginx container and 8080 on the Keycloak container. I have installed a let's encrypt certificate on abc.io at the domain level which I can see is working by the lock showing in the browser. I can click the lock and view the certificate information available in the browser and see it is pointing to abc.io.  No matter what I have tried, I haven't been able connect to Keycloak through the NGINX server. However, if I go into the bash console inside the Keycloak azure container instance, I can see curl request to http://kecloak running.

I can connect directly to the Keycloak container if I change the KC_HOSTNAME to https://[container-ininstance-name].azurecr.io. This shows me the administrator screen and then when I click the view admin link  I get a Loading admin hang which is expected because the hostname is still pointing at the abc.io domain. When I log in as a user I get, "failed to initialize Keycloak," error.

#here is my docker file for nginx

```
FROM nginx:latest

# copy the nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

# Expose ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS)
EXPOSE 80 443
```

Here is the nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;    
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name abc.io;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Here are my configurations and settings for Keycloak 23 standalone instance on window.

```
# nginx dockerfile

# For Ubuntu-based:
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-bullseye

# Create a directory for Keycloak
RUN mkdir -p /opt/keycloak

# Copy your Keycloak project files into the container
COPY ./keycloak /opt/keycloak

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak/bin

# Build Keycloak for production
RUN ./kc.sh build

# Expose ports (8080 for HTTP, 8443 for HTTPS)
EXPOSE 8080 8443

# Specify the command to start Keycloak in production mode
CMD ["./kc.sh", "start"]
```

Here is my Keycloak configuration

```
# Basic settings for running in production. Change accordingly before deploying the server.

# Database
db=mssql
db-username=abc-admin@pbs-abc-server
db-password=xxx
db-url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=KeycloakDB;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30
transaction-xa-enabled=false
proxy=edge
hostname=abc.io
http-port=8080
proxy-address-forwarding=true
http-enabled=true

# Path to the truststore file
kc.spi-truststore-file-file=/opt/keycloak/conf/pfx/mytruststore.jks

# Truststore password
kc.spi-truststore-file-password=xxx

# Truststore type
kc.spi-truststore-file-type=jks
```

Also, I can curl from within either container and access the Keycloak instance at http://keycloak but not http://keycloak:8080 (this should possible, since I am exposing port 8080 on the KC container). Anyways, I have spent so many days trying to get this to work. It should really be straight forward but it obviously is has many pitfalls. I will be incredibly grateful for the person who can untangle this mess for me. Believe me, I have spent way too much time on this!

Answer (score 0):

> A solution to connect to my application through the NGINX proxy server container instance, using Azure Container Apps.

Your goal is to route requests from your domain `abc.io` through the NGINX proxy to the Keycloak application.
Given your current setup, the NGINX server listens on ports 80 and 443, but it is primarily configured to route HTTP traffic (port 80).
For HTTPS traffic (port 443), which is your primary concern since you have an SSL certificate, you need to [configure NGINX to handle SSL termination](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) and forward the requests to [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/).

Your NGINX configuration snippet to handle HTTPS would be:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name abc.io;

    # SSL Configuration
    ssl_certificate /path/to/your/certificate.pem; # Replace with your certificate path
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/private.key; # Replace with your private key path

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

See [Keycloak / Using a reverse proxy](https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy) for more information on how to configure NGINX to work with Keycloak.

Make sure your NGINX container has access to the SSL certificate and key files.

> An explanation to why the reverse proxy is not forwarding request or why the Keycloak server is not receiving the requests.
> Remember, the "`Bring Your Own Certificate`" option was chosen and applied to the abc.io domain for the NGINX container.

It could be, as mentioned above, because your NGINX configuration might not be set up to handle HTTPS traffic properly.
Make sure the NGINX container can communicate with the Keycloak container. That includes correct DNS resolution for `http://keycloak` and open network paths between containers.

If the SSL certificate is not correctly installed or if there are issues with the certificate chain, browsers might refuse to connect, or NGINX might not serve the content correctly.

> an explanation to how the request is handled when it travels from the public facing edge (container cluster, firewall, or any thing I might have missed) to the proxied application (Keycloak in my case).

The request flow from the user's browser to the Keycloak application might look like this:

1. **Request Initiation**:
   A user makes an HTTPS request to `abc.io`.
2. **Azure Infrastructure**:
   The request hits Azure's infrastructure, where it is directed to your Azure Container Apps environment.
3. **SSL Termination at NGINX**:

   - NGINX, in your container environment, receives the request.
   - NGINX performs SSL termination, meaning it decrypts the HTTPS request.
4. **Adding Proxy Headers**:

   - NGINX adds essential proxy headers to the request, including `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto`, and `Host`.
   - These headers are important for Keycloak to understand the original request's context.
5. **Forwarding Request**:

   - NGINX forwards the request to the Keycloak container.
   - That forwarding is an internal request within your container environment, typically over HTTP.
6. **Keycloak's Proxy-Aware Configuration**:

   - Keycloak, configured to be aware of running behind a reverse proxy (`proxy-address-forwarding=true`), interprets the headers to understand the original protocol and client IP.
7. **Keycloak Processing**:

   - Keycloak receives and processes the request.
   - It then generates a response based on the request.
8. **Response to Client**:

   - The response is sent back to NGINX.
   - NGINX then sends this response back to the user's browser over HTTPS.
9. **Network Security Considerations**:

   - The internal communication between NGINX and Keycloak should be secured.
   - Network security configurations in Azure should make sure only NGINX can communicate with the Keycloak service.

```bash
+-------------------------+       +------------------------+       +---------------------+
|                         |       |                        |       |                     |
|   User's Browser (HTTPS)|  ---> | Azure Infrastructure   |  ---> | NGINX Proxy Server  |
|   (Request to abc.io)   |       | (abc.io domain route)  |       | (SSL Termination,   |
|                         |       |                        |       |  Proxy Headers)     |
+-------------------------+       +------------------------+       +---------------------+
                                                                             |
                                                                             |
                                                                             v
                                                                   +---------------------+
                                                                   |                     |
                                                                   |    Keycloak Server  |
                                                                   | (Proxy-Aware Config)|
                                                                   |                     |
                                                                   +---------------------+
```

It is important that throughout this flow, the configurations of both NGINX and Keycloak align with each other, especially in terms of network accessibility and hostname settings.

---

> it seems to be working now. I think that changing to port 80 in the Ingress settings is the difference.

Port 80 is the default port for HTTP traffic. By setting the Ingress to listen on port 80, you align with the standard port for HTTP, which might simplify routing and accessibility, especially in managed environments like Azure Container Apps.

Ingress controllers are typically configured to handle incoming traffic and then route it to the appropriate service within the container environment. By using port 80, you make sure the Ingress controller correctly handles and forwards the HTTP requests to your NGINX server.
Azure Container Apps might have specific expectations or optimizations for traffic on standard ports. By using port 80, you align with these expectations.

With the Ingress set to port 80, your NGINX container is likely receiving traffic on this port, which matches your NGINX configuration to listen on port 80 and redirect to HTTPS (port 443).

Comment: I have tried and understand all of this. However, it is unclear how it needs to be configured in the azure app container level. "This might look like this," is a generalization. The imperative for your answer to work, is that  there needs to be a clear way to configure Azure Container Apps in a way that the "Bring Your Own Certificate" no longer terminates the SSL(I am pretty sure this is done by default). Otherwise, it just won't work. If I am correct about this default behavior it leads me to believe there is something else going on at or beyond the proxy level preventing the proxy.

Comment: @jwize From what I understand of [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/custom-domains-certificates), Azure Container Apps, designed for simplicity and scalability, does not natively support the option to bypass the platform's SSL termination. That is in contrast to some other services like Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), where you have more control over the ingress and can manage SSL termination directly within your pods.

Comment: @jwize I do not see a straightforward setting in Azure Container Apps to disable the automatic SSL termination. That is why I described accepting the SSL termination at the platform level and then making sure your internal application (NGINX) is correctly configured to handle HTTP traffic and forward it to Keycloak.

Comment: So, I did give it another try. I pointed authorization.abc.io at nginx-container.azurecr.io at the NGINX container. Then I followed up by adding a custom domain but instead of adding the default or "Bring your Own Certificate". I chose add later. So, you would think that the https request would be passed on to the nginx server container but still nothing just a "Hmmm… can't reach this page". The page shows no lock so it is clear the default/own certificates aren't present.

Comment: It locally the termination works fine. Here is the setup and configured view.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tg9jdd?file=nginx.conf

Comment: @jwize Make sure the DNS changes for `authorization.abc.io` have fully propagated. DNS changes can take time to propagate globally. (`nslookup`, `dig`, `host`...). Is there anything in NGINX's error logs? Does the NGINX communicate with Keycloak internally within the Azure Container Apps environment? You can test this by exec-ing into the NGINX container and using `curl` to access the Keycloak service. Also, use tools like `curl` or `openssl s_client` to test the SSL connection from outside Azure directly to `authorization.abc.io`. That can help identify if there are SSL handshake issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256719/discussion-between-jwize-and-vonc).